# Using the SelectedIndex proprety of Pivot in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a Page with only a pivot in it. This page is **always cached**. Now whenever I navigate to this page, I want its contents and selections to be loaded from cached but I want to have the first `PivotItem` in view. 
XAML :

```
<Pivot x:Name="FilterPivot" 
        IsHeaderItemsCarouselEnabled="True"
        SelectedIndex="0">

    <PivotItem Header="Author" >               

        <ListBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind AuthorFacets, Mode=OneWay}"
                    Name="AuthorListBox"                         
                    SelectionMode="Multiple"
                    SelectionChanged="AuthorListBox_SelectionChanged">

            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>


            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:IFacet">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                        Text="{x:Bind read}"
                                        TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                        <Border Grid.Column="1"
                                    Background="Gray"
                                    MinWidth="25"
                                    CornerRadius="8">
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind num}"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            Padding="2"/>
                        </Border>

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

    </PivotItem>


    <PivotItem Header="Language">

        ....
        ....

    </PivotItem>

    <PivotItem Header="Learning Resource Type">

        ....
        ....

    </PivotItem>



    <PivotItem Header="Subject">

        ....
        ....

    </PivotItem>

    <PivotItem Header="Type">

        ....
        ....

    </PivotItem>

    <PivotItem Header="Education Level">

        ....
        ....

    </PivotItem>

    <PivotItem Header="Source">

        ....
        ....

    </PivotItem>

</Pivot>
```

This is my code behind:

```
public FilterPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    FilterPivot.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

This doesn't select the 0th index instead, it shows the cached `PivotItem` that was selected when the user navigated away from the view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `OnNavigatedTo` will be invoked **before** the `Pivot` control is even loaded, so setting the `SelectedIndex` won't affect its selection.

The easy workaround is to subscribe to the `Loaded` event instead and set it from there.

Just do the following within your `MainPage`'s constructor -

```
FilterPivot.Loaded += (s, e) => FilterPivot.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: *setting the SelectedIndex won't affect its selection* - sounds like a bug